# Обьясните поведение case, почему такое происходит?

Tags: java, case

Кто может обьяснить поведение `case` и считается ли это нормой?:) Вот рабочий код

```
package javaapplication12;

public class JavaApplication12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int type = 11;    
        switch(type){
            case 10:
                int i = 0;
                int max = 3;
                while(i<max){
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                break;
            case 11:
                i = 0; // <=======
                max = 2; // <========
                //МЫ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАЛИ КАК ОБЫЧНО INT NAME = 0
                //но компилятор выбрасывает
                //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable i is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
                //????? уберем INT, => NAME = 0 компилируется и работает, КАК ЭТО? переменная int i из другого case создается? но как
                while(i<max){
                    System.out.println("WHAT??");
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Java 8. Netbeans.
А если закоментить i = 0; или max = 2; получим исключение:) (код обернул в main для ясности)

Comment: Тут же написано переменная i  уже определена в методе main

Comment: Ага и поэтому case 10 Отрабатывается на ура(раз поверх case есть i), читаем внимательно код, или запускаем.

Comment: Почему вы i и max определяете в case 10?

Comment: Ну это же разные блоки, то, что объявляется во внутреннем блоке, не объявляется автоматом во внешнем.

Comment: Я как раз внимательно прочитал ваш код, а вы в свою очередь внимательно читайте комментарии. Объявление в case 10 "видно" в case 11.

Comment: Ага и поэтому тщательно модернизируете свои каменты:) во народ... Так почему он индусовский?

Comment: 1) Зачем это 2 раза      while(i<max){
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    i = i + 1;
                }. 2) Вы определили переменную в case 10, а как она должна определится в case 11?

Comment: Ха! Во даете, с каких пор while в индусы записали? Хорошо модернизируете свои каменты:)

Comment: С каких это пор while хорошие программисты в каждом case дублируют

Comment: Я дал пример, этот код я конечно не использую и где вы видели такое? и зачем?

Comment: Видел такое в вашем примере и отсюда делал анализ.

Comment: Хаха, во люди, во народ, поражаюсь. Ответ мне более ясный дали, и это далеко не ваш ответ.

Comment: Имея хоть начальные познания в английском можно было понять, на что ругалась программа. Если вы не поняли, то я вам в начале привел пояснение. На мой вопрос :" Почему вы i и max определяете в case 10?" вы ответили "Запустите код все узнаете:)". Так что действительно остается поражаться таким людям

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь дело в видимости переменных. Можно лишь раз в одном блоке кода объявить одну переменную.

При этом, в вашем случае хоть переменная и объявлена в `case 10` она, в случае, если не будет ей чего присвоено в `case 11` будет считаться объявленной, но не инициализированной. И, т.к. это не поле класса, то и значения по умолчанию ей присвоено не будет.

Чтобы оно у вас заработало, надо переменные эти вынести за `switch` блок или в каждом `case` создавать новую переменную с новым именем

Comment: Вот, дело в том что он рабочий. "case создавать новую переменную с новым именем " ага и джава еще будет держать i, max в памяти(и еще эти переменные)(хоть и пустые). А так ясное дело что джава создает, хоть и пустое, урок из этого ясен что в итоге надо переходить на if:)

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, case и if разные и нельзя сказать что один из них лучше другого. Это просто разные инструменты. На начальном этапе задумываться о том будет ли лишняя переменная в памяти хранится - не стоит. Сначала лучше в базовых вещах разобраться - в операторах, областях видимости etc

Comment: Данную особенность можно очень просто объяснить, ведь все мы знаем что у case есть break, (на примере с 10 11) если убрать break у 10 контейнера получим то что выполнится еще и 11 контейнер. Исходя из этого джава попросту не может разобратся с этими переменными и поэтому все переменные(встречающие более 1 раз) создает сразу. "Сначала лучше в базовых вещах разобраться - в операторах, областях видимости etc" не понял... "На начальном этапе" с чего вы решили.

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, свой вывод я сделал на основе того, что вы не разобрались с `switch` оператором и затрудняетесь чётко сформулировать вопрос. Во всяком случае я лично до сих пор не могу понять что именно вы спросили.

Comment: Я и спросил что это за данная особенность что переменные в контейнере 11(похожие с именем на переменные из контейнера 10) могут изменять свое значение без создания самой переменной. Но подумав и прочитав ваш комментарий я понел данную особенность(которую озвучил здесь же, выше).

Comment: @ДенисКотляров дело в том, что метки в case - это не контейнеры. это просто метки. поэтому к ним вообще нельзя применять слово "в".

Answer (score 2):

Пишут же:

> Uncompilable source code - variable i is already defined

Просто примите, что так делать нельзя. Либо выносите нужные переменные выше switch:

```
int i = 0;
int max = 2;
switch( type ) {
// ...
```

Либо ограничивайте их видимость внутри каждого case:

```
case 10: 
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 2;
    // ...
}
break;

case 11: 
{
    int i = 0;
    int max = 2;
    // ...
}
break;
```

> Вот, дело в том что он рабочий

Только плоховато рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что метки `case` внутри `switch` - это не некие "контейнеры", как вы их воспринимаете.

Сам по себе блок `switch`/`case` был скопирован в Java из С-подобных языков. А в них синтаксис меток вида `case <value>:` следовал общему синтаксису меток `label:`. Которые, по сути, были просто именованными местами в коде, в которые в любой момент можно было прыгнуть. С помощью `goto`:

```
int main()
{
    for (...)
    {
        for (...)
        {
            if (something)
                goto stop;
        }
    }

    // some code

stop: 
    // some code
}
```

`switch`, по сути, просто позволял выбрать целевую метку для прыжка на основе значения.

Java скопировала `switch`, но не скопировала `goto`. Поэтому поведение кажется вам странным.

Если ваш код отформатировать так, чтобы метки перестали казаться частью кода, и стали читаться именно как отметки для прыжка, механизм работы `switch` станет более очевидным:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int type = 11;    
    switch(type){
case 10:
            int i = 0;
            int max = 3;
            while(i<max){
                System.out.println("OK");
                i = i + 1;
            }
            break;
case 11:
            i = 0; // <=======
            break;
    }
}
```

По той же причине в конце блока для каждой метки приходится писать `break;`, чтобы выполнение не "провалилось" дальше.